# Problems with partialview data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a problem with a partial view. The first time when it is rendered everything is ok, but after that some data is loosed.

This is how my page should look: this is when the partial view is rendered the first time

[image]

but when I'm clicking on a category to check his subcategories, the image is null, it is not visible anymore. (only the name is visible)

[image]

This is my partial view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<OnlineCarStore.Models.CategoriesVM>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubCategories", "Product"))
    {
        <div class="list-group col-sm-3" style="width:280px;">
            @{var selected = string.Empty;
                if (@HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCar"] == null)
                {
                    selected = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    selected = @HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCar"].ToString();
                }

                foreach (var c in Model)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("SubCategories", "Product", new { selected = @selected, id = @c.ID, category = @c.CategoryName })" class="list-group-item">
                        <span> @c.CategoryName</span>
                    </a>
                }
            }
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @foreach (var c in Model)
            {
            <div class="card-group" style="width:200px; display: inline-block">
                <div class="card card">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("SubCategories", "Product", new { selected = @HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCar"].ToString(), id = @c.ID, category = @c.CategoryName })" id="linkOnImg" class="card-group">
                        <img class="card-img-top center-block" src="@string.Format("../content/images/categories/{0}.jpg", @c.AtpID)" alt=@c.CategoryName style="padding-top: 5px">
                        <div class="card-text text-center">
                            <p class="category-card-title ">
                                <span class="text-muted">@c.CategoryName</span>
                            </p>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
                }
</div>
```

and this is the Subcategoris view, where the partial view is rendered second time:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">       
    @Html.Partial("/Views/Home/CategorieTypes.cshtml");
```

Here is the Product controller Subcategories method:

```
 public ActionResult SubCategories(string selected, int id, string category)
    {
        List<CategoriesVM> listOfCategories = new List<CategoriesVM>();

        var list = db.Categories.ToList();
        var root = list.GenerateTree(c => c.ID, c => c.ParentId).ToList();



        TreeItem<Categories> found = null;
        var test = new TreeItem<Categories>();

        foreach (var rootNode in root)
        {
            found = TreeGenerator.Find(rootNode, (n) => n.Item.ID == id);
            if (found != default(TreeItem<Categories>))
            {
                test = found;
                break;
            }                
        }

        foreach (var item in found.Children.ToList())
        {
            CategoriesVM categoryv = new CategoriesVM();
            categoryv.ID = item.Item.ID;
            categoryv.AtpID = item.Item.AtpID;
            categoryv.Childrens = item.Children.ToList();
            categoryv.CategoryName = item.Item.AtpName;//.Name;

            listOfCategories.Add(categoryv);
        }

        SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.Title = selected + " " + category;

        var tests = found.Children.ToList();
        if (found.Children.ToList().Count == 0 )
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
           return View("SubCategories", listOfCategories);
        }            
    }
```

I've checked in developer tool if the source for the image is correct, and although it is correct, the image is not showed:

[image]

[image]

Can you please help me in this problem? What I do wrong? Why the images don't appear after the first render of the partial view? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check the source of images in browser developer tool and confirm if it is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of the partial view is `/Views/Home/CategorieTypes.cshtml` and the path of the images is `/Content/images/categories`. 
In the partial view you are using `../content/images/categories/` as the path of the images which means that it will search for the path `/Views/Content/Images/Categories` which is invalid.

Remove the two dots in the `src` property and add a `~` so it will be like: 
`~/Content/Images/Categories/{img}`.

**or**
Add one more `../` in order to go one level down to the directory like:
`../../Content/Images/Categories/{img}`

Comment: Thank you!!! That was the problem. I removed the 2 dots, and now it's working :) Thanks